# how can i add image in autocomplete search jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
 public function search(Request $request){




    $search = $request->term;
    $users = User::where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('username','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();
    $data = [];
    foreach ($users as $key => $value){
        $data [] =['id' =>$value->id, 'value' =>$value->name,
            'username'=> $value->username,
            'image'=>$value->image
            ];

    }
    return response($data);
```

AJAX In blade . [image]

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
  //  source: data,
    source: "{{ URL::to('autocom-search') }}",
    minLength: 2,
    select:function (key,value) {

      console.log(value);
    }

})
```

I want to show image with name.  this code is working properly for simple text like name
dsa
asd
dasd
das
dsad
asdas
dsa
das
das
dad

Comment: You shouldn't [mix PHP and JS](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-put-js-and-css-in-blade-templates-and-do-not-put-any-html-in-php-classes)

Comment: Follow the [Custom Data and Display example](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) in the docs